# Increment i inside for loop of foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to produce an output as below. For each item in @ViewBag.Table, duplicate 3 times and then increment the value i by 1 for each foreach iteration

eg:
Values return by @ViewBag.Table { "Test", "AA", "Hello" } 
Output:

```
Test   1
Test   2
Test   3
AA     4
AA     5
AA     6
Hello  7
Hello  8
Hello  9
```

How could this be done?

```
@foreach(var item in @ViewBag.Table)
{
  for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
  {       
    @item.Column1 + " " + i;
  }
}
```

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev changing the i to j will keep repeat the value 1, 2, 3. I need the next one to be 4, 5, 6, etc. What the expectation is increment the i as shown in the sample above. And i can't declare variable i outside of the foreach loop.

Comment: You can increment `i` the same way as you already showing for `j`... Not sure what stops you from doing that...

Comment: Why can't you declare `i` outside the loops?  If not, where *did* you declare it?

Comment: `@item.Column1 + " " + i++;` ?

Comment: Oh, missed the bit about not declaring `i` outside the loop. Although that just sounds wrong anyway.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I have tried putting for(int i =0; i <= 90; i++) outside of foreach loop, between foreach loop and for(int j) loop and inside for(int j) loop but it does not produce the result as expected

it would be good if you can show a solution

Comment: @Dan-o that was what i am thinking now. where can i declare the i? not that if the i is declare outside foreach loop is is not accessible inside

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can increment `i` anywhere inside the `foreach` loop, you can even do it on the same line where you assign it's value:

```
@{int i = 1;}
@foreach(var item in @ViewBag.Table)
{
  for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
  {       
    @item.Column1 + " " + i++;
  }
}
```

PS. As [Ceisc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4074984/ceisc) mentioned, a standard way to start begin the loop is to start it from 0.

Comment: Given that the value of `j` isn't used, I'd probably have gone with `for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)` as I prefer to have everything start at zero.

Comment: @Ceisc that's how the OP does it, so I've decided to leave it like this.

Comment: Yeah, I appreciate that is how the OP had it. My comment was more to suggest to them that it's more standard to do zero-based rather than a complaint that your answer didn't.

Comment: @Ceisc yeah, that's true, I will include the comment about it :)

Comment: well i guess i am declaring @int i =1; instead of @{int i = 1 } therefore it is not readable inside foreach loop

Comment: Correct answer but it's woth noting that, in general,  a View shouldn't be doing so much.